# Python - socket.error: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have written a chat server but I cannot bind my socket to an IP address:

```
import sys
import os
import socket

HOST = "194.118.168.131"
SOCKET_LIST = []
RECV_BUFFER = 4096 
PORT = 9009

def chat_server():

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)
...
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 83, in <module>
    sys.exit(chat_server())
  File "server.py", line 20, in chat_server
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

What's wrong with my code?

---

I didn't find an answer on:

['Connection aborted.', error(99, 'Cannot assign requested address') error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992881/connection-aborted-error99-cannot-assign-requested-address-error-in-pyt),
[socket.error[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460287/socket-errorerrno-99-cannot-assign-requested-address),
[bind: cannot assign requested address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471885/bind-cannot-assign-requested-address)
[Cannot assign requested address - possible causes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640619/cannot-assign-requested-address-possible-causes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By checking *errno.h*, errno 99 is *EADDRNOTAVAIL*. The man page *bind(2)* says:

> EADDRNOTAVAIL A nonexistent interface was requested or the requested address was not local.

It is often caused by a wrong IP address. You can use the command 
*ifconfig* to check whether your machine has this IP address.

Comment: Thank you! Now everything is fine

Comment: wrong IP address in the machine I am trying to connect?